# how to i add objects to an array ? ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, object

How do I fill the animal list array randomly with cats and dogs??

```
class Dog
  def speak
    puts "woof"
  end
end

class Cat
  def
    puts "meow"
  end
end

class PetLover
  def random_animal     
  end

  Animallist = Array.new(9)
  #Animallist[]
end
```

Comment: Your question doesn't show a lot of effort... have you tried anything at all before asking?

Answer (score 2):

I think the following will be of some help to get started:

```
class Dog
  def speak
    puts "woof"
  end
end

class Cat
  def speak
    puts "meow"
  end
end

class PetLover
  attr_accessor :species
  def initialize
    @species = [Dog, Cat]
  end

  def random_animal  
    @species[rand(@species.size)].new
  end

  def animals(n)
    ary = []
    n.times do 
      ary << random_animal
    end
    ary
  end
end

pl = PetLover.new
p pl.animals(10)
```

Comment: If you are using 1.9 `random_animal` can be simplified to `@species.sample.new`.

Comment: Of course. But since it looks like the author is still learning, I thought this definition was more didactic.